# Wordpress Custom Local Avatar not showing in comments

Tags: comments, author, avatar

I have built my own frontend user avatar upload script.
Now the avatars show fine in the user section in admin and in the top panel. However I can't seem to get them showing in the comments and author sections of the site.

I use the following get_avatar code

```
  add_filter ('get_avatar', function($avatar_html, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt) {
    $avatar = get_user_meta($id_or_email,'avatar',true);
    if( $avatar ) {
        return '<img src="'.$avatar.'" width="96" height="96" alt="Avatar" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" id="wad_profile_avatar" />';
    } else {
        return $avatar_html;
}
}, 10, 5);
```

Any ideas how I can get it to show in comments also?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and now my frontend avatar script is fully functioning.

Happy days :)

I ended up scrapping the above code and using this.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_avatar_data', 'wad_avatar_meta', 10, 2 );

function wad_avatar_meta( $args, $id_or_email ){
    $user_avatar_meta_key = 'avatar';

    if( is_object( $id_or_email ) && isset( $id_or_email->comment_ID ) ){
        $id_or_email = get_comment( $id_or_email );
    }

    if( $id_or_email instanceof WP_Post ){
        $user_id = $id_or_email->post_author;
    }

    if( $id_or_email instanceof WP_Comment ){
        if( ! empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) ){
            $user_id = $id_or_email->user_id;
        } elseif( ! empty( $id_or_email->comment_author_email ) ){
            // If user_id not available, set as email address to handle below
            $id_or_email = $id_or_email->comment_author_email;
        }
    }

    if( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ){
        $user_id = $id_or_email;
    } elseif( is_string( $id_or_email ) && strpos( $id_or_email, '@' ) ){
        $id_or_email = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );
    }

    if( $id_or_email instanceof WP_User ){
        $user_id = $id_or_email->ID;
    }

    if( ! empty( $user_id ) && is_numeric( $user_id ) ){

        $meta_val = maybe_unserialize( get_user_meta( $user_id, $user_avatar_meta_key, TRUE ) );

        if( ! empty( $meta_val ) ){

            if( is_array( $meta_val ) && ! empty( $meta_val[0] ) ){
                $meta_val = $meta_val[0];
            }

            if( filter_var( $meta_val, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) ){
                $args['url'] = $meta_val;
            }

        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```